# My iPhone 5 isn't downloading apps

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, install

There are a few apps that I found online that I'm trying to download, but my phone isn't letting me. When I click the link and it brings me to the app store, I click the "get" button, and then the "install" button, but instead of recognizing that, it just reloads and I have to click it again. I've tried it many times with many different apps, but it just keeps reloading until I give up. It didn't even give me an error message. I know I have plenty of storage, so that isn't the problem. Thank you for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

There is a service disruption affecting the all iTunes stores. [See Here](https://www.apple.com/ca/support/systemstatus/)

> Wednesday, 14 October, 2015
>
> All Store Services - Some users are affected
> Users may be unable to access multiple services and stores or make purchases.

Next time this happens, check http://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/

Comment: Thank you! Do you know when it's likely to be over?